# OAuth 2.0 and Phonegap's InAppBrowser for Authentication

Tags: javascript, cordova, oauth, inappbrowser

I am trying to use Oauth 2.0 to authenticate users signing in their google accounts. I will need access to their names and email addresses for this. I am using phonegap's InAppBrowser to do this.

So far I have this:

```
function openPage() {  

    var login_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth" + '?' + $.param({ client_id: "(not shown)", redirect_uri: "http://www.google.com", response_type: "token", scope: "openid profile email" });

    var loginWindow = window.open(login_url, '_blank', 'location=yes');

    loginWindow.addEventListener('loadstop', function(e) { 
        var url = e.url;
        var access_token = url.split("access_token=")[1];
        validateToken(access_token);
    });

        function validateToken(token) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=' + token,
            data: null,
            success: function(responseText){  
                alert("Validation Success!");
                getUserInfo(token);
            },  
            dataType: "jsonp"  
        });
    }

    function getUserInfo(token) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=' + token,
            data: null,
            success: function(resp) {
                user    =   resp;
                alert(JSON.stringify(user));
            },
            dataType: "jsonp"
        });
    }

    }
```

The validation of the token works everytime, but once it calls getUserInfo() the JSON returned is filled with errors and invalid credential strings. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to set the token in `Authorization` header as per the documentation for Userinfo endpoint found [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect#validatinganidtoken)